# Как заполнить массив double через цикл for?

Tags: java, массивы

Для вывода трёхмерного пространства необходимо таким образом заполнить массив, вроде как лёгкое дело, но мне в районе `x[i],y[j],z[i][j]` выводит ошибку:

> required type int, provided double

Как это исправить?

```java
public static void show() {
    double[] x = new double[11];
    double[] y = new double[11];
    double[][] z = new double[x.length][y.length];
    for (double i = 0.0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.2) {
        x[i] = i;
        for (double j = 0.0; j <= 1.0; j += 0.2) {
            y[j] = j;
            z[i][j] = (x[i] + y[j]) / (4 * x[i] * y[j] + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: индекс массива это целое число!

Answer (score 0):

Не надо путать *индекс* элемента массива и *значение* этого элемента. Индекс - это целое число всегда, а `double` - это в данном случае значение.

```java
double[] x = new double[11];
double[] y = new double[11];
double[][] z = new double[x.length][y.length];
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i] = (double) i * 0.2;
    for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
        y[j] = (double) j * 0.2;
        z[i][j] = (x[i] + y[j]) / (4 * x[i] * y[j] + 1);
    }
}
```